# XML - python : insert unclosed tag

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm performing test with POST and PUT method on a REST service.

Basically I use in both cases this xml:

```
xml = \
"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<quser xmlns="http://user" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom">
<username>a_username</username>
<password>blablabla</password>
<first_name></first_name>
<last_name></last_name>
<email>anemail@gogle.com</email>
<degree></degree>
<institution></institution>
<fields>
    <role>reader</role>
</fields>
<research_areas></research_areas>
</quser>"""
```

To POST this xml I use this code:

```
def post_resource(url, xml, content_type='application/xml'):
    try:
        request = urllib2.Request(url=url, data=xml)
        request.add_header(key='content-type', val=content_type)
        response = opener.open(request)
        print_response(response)
    except HTTPError, e:
        print "Error: %s\n%s" % (e, e.read())
```

To perform changes (PUT) i use this code:

```
def put_resource(url, xml, username=None, password=None):
    try:
        if username and password:
            str = "%s:%s" % (username, password)
            b64 = str.encode('base64')
        request = urllib2.Request(url=url, data=xml)
        request.add_header(key='content-type', val='application/xml')
        request.add_header(key='Authorization', val='Basic %s' % b64)
        request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
        response = opener.open(request)
        print_response(response)
    except HTTPError, e:
        print "Error: %s\n%s" % (e, e.read())
```

Problem:

When I POST data everything goes fine. But when I tried to make changes on a resource, with PUT, I send the same xml with only a change in the email address, and the XML parser returns :

`insert unclosed token: line 14, column 4`

I've no idea how a similar xml can be cause of a parsing error in the PUT case and not in the POST case. Any suggestion is welcome! Thanks

**EDIT**

More details could help...
I've access to the service implementation, and the parsing is made as follow:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML

try:
    node_tree = XML(data.strip())
    return self._parse_xml_node_to_dict(node_tree)
 except ParseError, e:
```

When I debug, the exception it thrown when XML constructor is called with `data.strip()` argument.
@thebjorn: I don't have any xml schema

@mzjn:
Thanks! So I've to track down where it happens, but the content of `data` is truncated somewhere. Here is the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<quser xmlns="http://user" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom">
<username>victorinox2</username>
<password>42b564oq</password>
<first_name></first_name>
<last_name></last_name>
<email>gosdfsdfsddacyer@gmail.com</email>
<degree></degree>
<institution></institution>
<fields>
    <role>reader</role>
</fields>
<research_areas></research_areas>
</quse
```

I use Django and it seems that the request.raw_post_data contains already the truncated data. But when I ste data in `urllib2.Request(url=url, data=xml)` the `xml` content is not truncated...

Comment: You may want to try the Requests package instead of urllib2 for your HTTP PUT, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-any-way-to-do-http-put-in-python

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the `data` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, as I said in my previous EDIT, the string transmitted is truncated when it arrives on the service side. 
I couldn't find out if it was Django-related or urllib2-related.

Anyway, I figured this out by adding two new lines at the end of the string contained in the `xml` varibale. One new line wasn't enough there was still the `>` truncated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the schema of the service you're using, you could always try to validate the xml yourself... might give you a more informative error message..