# PUT request from tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient

Tags: python, tornado, urllib

Is there any way to perform PUT request in tornado httpclient?

For example are there any ways to replace `urllib` with [Requests Library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html#)?

Or maybe subclass own client and inject there construction from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-any-way-to-do-http-put-in-python) answer:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request('http://example.org', data='your_put_data')
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'your/contenttype')
request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
url = opener.open(request)
```

Any painless patches, hacks, suggestions..

I want this construction to work propertly:

```
 response = yield gen.Task(http_client.fetch, opt.site_url + '/api/user/', method="PUT", body=urlencode(pdata))
```

For now it's not sending body.

Comment: sorry but why using urllib since you've http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp, tornado using it by default, if I'm not missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, Tornado doesn't use urllib (presumably it blocks). The trick to using httpclient for anything more complicated than a basic GET is to create an [HTTPRequest](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html#request-objects).

Untested, but should work:

```
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest
request = HTTPRequest(opt.site_url + '/api/user/', method="PUT", body=urlencode(pdata))
response = yield gen.Task(http_client.fetch, request)
```

Comment: This needs to be tested. Anybody tested if this works? Or has any complicationss?