# How do I insert a row in my google fusion table using Python

Tags: python, google-api, oauth-2.0, urllib2, google-fusion-tables

I am working on a project and part of it involves inserting rows in to a Google Fusion Table for the Project from a python script. I have spent the last couple days trying to figure out just how to do that and I am officially confused.

My research seems to indicate that I need to use Oauth 2.0 to access the API. In doing so I can successfully get an access token but I can't seem to successfully get a refresh token. I'm not sure if this is going to hamper my ability to successfully integrate access to my Fusion Table with my Python code.

The second problem I am having is that I don't really understand how exactly to code inserting a row in my table. Most of the material I have found on it is from the deprecated Fusion Tables SQL API and I don't fully understand the new way of doing it.

I'm a beginner at this sort of thing and any direction to help me is very much appreciated!

Edit:
So the code I have working so far looks like this:

```
client_id = "<client_i>"
client_secret = "<client_secret>"
table_id = "<table_id>"

access_token = ""
refresh_token = "<refresh_token>"

#   the refresh token is used to request a new access token
data = urllib.urlencode({
  'client_id': client_id,
  'client_secret': client_secret,
  'refresh_token': refresh_token,
  'grant_type': 'refresh_token'})
request = urllib2.Request(
  url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  data=data)
request_open = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response = request_open.read()
request_open.close()
tokens = json.loads(response)
access_token = tokens['access_token']

#   Read the table
request_read = urllib2.Request(
  url='https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?%s' % \
    (urllib.urlencode({'access_token': access_token,
                       'sql': 'SELECT * FROM table_id'})))
request_open = urllib2.urlopen(request_read)
response = request_open.read()
request_open.close()
print response
```

And my code for trying to insert a new row into my table:

```
date = str(datetime.now().date())
time = str(datetime.now().time())
query = 'INSERT INTO table_id (Date,Time,Saskatoon,Regina,MeadowLake)VALUES(date,time,60.01,60.02,59.99)'
data = urllib2.Request(
  url='https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?%s' % \
    (urllib.urlencode({'access_token': access_token,
                       'sql': query})))
request_open = urllib2.urlopen(data)
```

When I run this i get

> HTTP Error 400: HTTP GET can only be used for select queries.

I am know I'm supposed to be making a POST not a GET for the INSERT, I'm just not sure what needs to change in my code for that to happen. 
Sorry for being a noob.

2ND EDIT:

Sorry for making this longer but I feel it is pertinent to show where I've gotten so far. I switched to the library requests and things have gotten somewhat easier however I still haven't successfully made a POST. My new code for importing rows is as follows:

```
def importRows(self):
    print 'IMPORT ROWS'
    date = str(datetime.now().date())
    time = str(datetime.now().time())
    data = {'Date': date,
            'Time': time,
            'Saskatoon': '60.01',
            'Regina': '59.95'}
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/%s/import/%s' % \
          (tableid, self.params) # self.params is access token
    importRow = requests.post(url, params=data)

    print importRow.status_code
    print importRow.text
```

Which gives me

```
400
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "fusiontables",
    "reason": "badImportInputEmpty",
    "message": "Content is empty."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Content is empty."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If your application needs offline access to a Google API, then the request for an authorization code should include the access_type parameter, where the value of that parameter is offline.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Then, to obtain an access token using the refresh token you send a POST request including `grant_type` with value `refresh_token`.

Basically, the way SQL works is you send POST requests using a subset of SQL statements `https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=STATEMENT_HERE`

Refer to

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/query
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference

Edit:

Since you are using `urllib2` without a data parameter, it defaults to GET. To fix this you should either use another HTTP library that allows for explicitly specifying method (like [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or `httplib`) or do something like this:

```
query = "INSERT INTO %s(EXAMPLE_COL1,EXAMPLE_COL2) VALUES"\
        "('EXAMPLE_INFO1','EXAMPLE_INFO2')" % table_id # Single quotes
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request('https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?%s' % \
    (urllib.urlencode({'access_token': access_token,
                       'sql': query})),
    headers={'Content-Length':0})      # Manually set length to avoid 411 error
request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'    # Change HTTP request method
response = opener.open(request).read()
print response
```

Important to notice:

1. Monkey patch the method to do what we want (POST with an empty body) otherwise we would receive `HTTP Error 400: HTTP GET can only be used for SELECT queries`.
2. Manually specify that we do not have a body (`Content-Length` is `0`) otherwise we would receive `HTTP Error 411: Length Required`.
3. Must use **double quotes with single quotes inside** or **escape the inner quotes** to submit strings via the query. In other words, `"INSERT INTO %s(EXAMPLE_COL1,EXAMPLE_COL2) VALUES(EXAMPLE_INFO1,EXAMPLE_INFO2)" % table_id` does not work.

   If we tried to use the previous line we would get something like `HTTP Error 400: Parse error near 'SOME_STRING' (line X, position Y)`

See for info on changing method with urllib2:

[Is there any way to do HTTP PUT in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-any-way-to-do-http-put-in-python)

Comment: Ok I have no problem with getting a refresh token now but I am still stuck on what the code looks like to insert a row in to my fusion table.

Comment: Can you post what you have so far? What errors are you getting? It's a bit weird since you use POST but you don't use a body at all (its blank). The info is submitted as you would GET requests.

Comment: Creating the opener didn't work, I got some errors I couldn't get past. So I switched to trying requests. The result is that doing GET requests is really easy and works but I haven't had any luck with POST.

Comment: Wow, OK point 3. was totally my problem! I am now able to make POST requests. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Thanks!