# Using urllib2 cannot change HTTP method to PUT

Tags: python, http, urllib2

Why can I not change method to PUT.  Can I change to PUT without too many code changes?

Here is my code:

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)   

#code to change method to PUT
opener.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'

print "now using method:", meth  # prints now using PUT

try:
    r = opener.open("http://the_url")
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    if hasattr(e, 'code'):
        report += "HTTP error status " + str(e.code) + " FAIL\n"
        if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            print "HTTP Error reason " + e.reason
    else:
        report += "HTTP error occurred FAIL\n"
```

But I get runtime error
HTTP Error reason Request method 'POST' not supported
PUT session test
HTTP error status 405 FAIL

Comment: Please, your life will be easier: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Please provide a [short, self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org) demonstrating your problem. The code you've included isn't one: it crashes if you try to run it, and uses variables (e.g. `meth`) not defined anywhere.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-any-way-to-do-http-put-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems urllib2 only supports GET and POST.  I decided to use Apache Requests lib instead.

The opener.get_method = lambda: 'PUT' is some code I found on the web.  It doesn't actually change the verb used to send the request, even though if you get_method it will reply with whatever you changed it to.

For example, in my case, because request contained data (not actually shown in example above) it sends a POST.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-any-way-to-do-http-put-in-python 
You do `request.get_method` not `opener.get_method`. Although it is probably better to subclass `urllib2.Request` and overide `get_method()`