# bottle python put equivalent to post for data

Tags: python, bottle

Im using the awesome python bottle app as a JSON server.

`POST` is working fine but not `PUT`

I use the following in POST to retrieve the POST'ed data.

```
data = request.body.getvalue()
if data: 
    ...
```

Whats the equiv for capturing PUT data?

Secondly, do I use the same `--data` option on curl for testing (aside from changing the -X verb from `POST` to `PUT`

```
curl -X PUT --data '{"key":"value"}' http://myserver.com/1/object/type
```

Comment: Seems this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-any-way-to-do-http-put-in-python

Comment: thats link covers using libcurl by the client to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Whats the equiv for capturing PUT data?

See if this does the trick:

```
data = request.body.read()
```

---

> do I use the same --data option on curl for testing

Yep, that should work.