# Doing PUT using Python urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to do PUT to REST using urllib2 following the example I found on stackoverflow:

[Is there any way to do HTTP PUT in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-any-way-to-do-http-put-in-python)

I don't understand why I get error an error.

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
import urllib2
import json

content_header = {'Content-type':'application/json',
                 'Accept':'application/vnd.error+json,application/json',
                 'Accept-Version':'1.0'}

baseURL = "http://some/put/url/"


f = open("somefile","r")
data = json.loads(f.read())

request = urllib2.Request(url=baseURL, data=json.dumps(jsonObj), headers=content_header)
request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT' #if I remove this line then the POST works fine.

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

print response.read()
```

if I remove the PUT option I'm trying to set then it posts it find but it will error out when I try and set get_method to PUT.

To be sure that the REST services aren't causing the issues I tried using cURL to do a PUT and it worked fine.

Comment: What is the full traceback of your exception?

Comment: And if you are not fussed about installing a new Python library, [`python-requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) can handle `PUT` without extra hacks and is much easier to use.

Comment: FWIW I strongly recommend using the `requests` library for any HTTP stuff in Python.  The API for the build-in HTTP client functionality is no good.  This doesn't amount to an answer, though, as your question specifies `urllib2`.

Comment: I third the suggestion of `requests`

Comment: I have to agree requests make life so much easier.

Answer (score 13):

While aaronfay's answer is good and works, I think that given that there are only 3 HTTP methods other than GET (and you are only worried about PUT), it is clearer and simpler to just define the Request sub-classes per method.

For example:

```
class PutRequest(urllib2.Request):
    '''class to handling putting with urllib2'''

    def get_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 'PUT'
```

Then to use:

```
request = PutRequest(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=content_header)
```

Comment: It's not necessary to override any method (in this case `__init__`) in a subclass if the subclass implementation simply calls the superclass implementation.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but how do you actually execute this request?

Comment: urllib2.urlopen(request)

Answer (score 10):

As others have noted, `requests` is a fantastic library. However, if you are in a situation where `requests` cannot be used (say an ansible module development or similar), there is another way, as demonstrated by the author of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/logic/2715756):

```
import urllib2

class MethodRequest(urllib2.Request):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'method' in kwargs:
            self._method = kwargs['method']
            del kwargs['method']
        else:
            self._method = None
        return urllib2.Request.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._method is not None:
            return self._method
        return urllib2.Request.get_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Usage:

```
>>> req = MethodRequest(url, method='PUT')
```

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but how do you actually execute this request?

Comment: urllib2.urlopen(req)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
import urllib

data=urllib.urlencode(jsonObj)
```

Instead of `json.dumps`. It works for me.

Comment: URL encoding and JSON encoding are fundamentally different things, and the encoding (URL encoding vs JSON) is orthogonal to the HTTP method (POST vs PUT)