# Sending Multiple Files in a single Request to API

Tags: c#, api, rest, client-server

I am fairly new to API's. I am writing a "simple" API that will convert .docx files to .pdf files and return the pdf's back to the client for saving. I have the code working for a single file but I wanted to code the API to handle multiple files in a single request. Now the API is not receiving the request. I can provide the working code with a single file if requested.

I am sure I am missing something simple. Please see below and see if anyone see's something that I could be doing better or why the API is not receiving the POST request.

Client:

```
        List<string> documents = new List<string>();

        private async void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseApiUrl);
                //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

                // Add an Accept header for JSON format.    
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, BaseApiUrl + ApiUrl);

                foreach (string s in docPaths)
                {
                    byte[] bte;
                    bte = File.ReadAllBytes(docPath);

                    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Convert.ToBase64String(bte));
                    documents.Add(data);                    
                }

                using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    foreach (string s in documents)
                    {
                        //add content to form data
                        formData.Add(new StringContent(s, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                    }

                    // List of Http Reponse Messages
                    var conversions = documents.Select(doc => client.PostAsync(BaseApiUrl + ApiUrl, formData)).ToList();

                    //Wait for all the requests to finish
                    await Task.WhenAll(conversions);

                    //Get the responses
                    var responses = conversions.Select
                        (
                            task => task.Result
                        );

                    foreach (var r in responses)
                    {
                        // Extract the message body
                        var s = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        SimpleResponse res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleResponse>(s);

                        if (res.Success)
                        {
                            byte[] pdf = Convert.FromBase64String(res.Result.ToString());

                            // Save the PDF here
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           // Log issue
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

API: This is not getting the request so this function is not complete. I need to figure out why it not being hit.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<List<SimpleResponse>> Post([FromBody]string request)
        {
            var response = new List<SimpleResponse>();
            Converter convert = new Converter();

            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            foreach (var requestContents in provider.Contents)
            {
                try
                {
                    //var result = convert.CovertDocToPDF(requestContents, WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempDocPath"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempPdfPath"]);

                    //response.Add(new SimpleResponse() { Result = result, Success = true });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    response.Add(new SimpleResponse() { Success = false, Exception = ex, Errors = new List<string>() { string.Format("{0}, {1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException?.Message ?? "") } });
                }
            }

            return response;
        }
```

SimpleResponse Model:

```
    public class SimpleResponse
    {
        public object Result { get; set; }
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public Exception Exception { get; set; }
        public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
    }
```

### UPDATE

Did suggestions made by @jdweng and I am getting a null response on the API POST

Client:

```
        public async void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseApiUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

                // Add an Accept header for JSON format.    
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//application/json
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, BaseApiUrl + ApiUrl);

                List<string> requests = new List<string>();
                byte[] bte;

                // New Code per the suggestion
                foreach (string s in docPaths)
                {
                     bte = File.ReadAllBytes(s);

                    requests.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(bte));
                }
                // End new code

                string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requests);

                request.Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage response1 = client.PostAsync(BaseApiUrl + ApiUrl, request.Content).Result;
                Task<string> json = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                SimpleResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleResponse>(json.Result);
                //result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result).ToString();

                if (response.Success)
                {
                    bte = Convert.FromBase64String(response.Result.ToString());

                    if (File.Exists(tempPdfPath))
                    {
                        File.Delete(tempPdfPath);
                    }
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempPdfPath, bte);
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Server:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<List<SimpleResponse>> Post([FromBody]string request)
        {
            // The request in NULL....

            List<SimpleResponse> responses = new List<SimpleResponse>();

            List<string> resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(request) as List<string>;
            try
            {
                Converter convert = new Converter();

                foreach (string s in resp)
                {
                    var result = convert.CovertDocToPDF(request, WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempDocPath"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempPdfPath"]);

                    responses.Add(new SimpleResponse()
                    {
                        Result = result,
                        Success = true
                    });
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responses.Add(new SimpleResponse()
                {
                    Result = null,
                    Success = true,
                    Exception = ex,
                    Errors = new List<string>() { string.Format("{0}, {1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException?.Message ?? "") }
                });
            }

            return responses;
        }
```

Comment: You need to send a mime request.  The mime attachments start with two dashes (header line) followed by a carriage return.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289602/create-mime-multipart-request-containing-multiple-http-requests

Comment: @jdweng - I tried your suggestion and the API is still not receiving the post request.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @jdweng No errors at all

Comment: The underlining code is using XmlSerialization. the default when you use an array/list is for the Net library to generate two xml tags like <SimpleResponses><<SimpleResponse></SimpleResponse><SimpleResponse></SimpleResponse><SimpleResponse></SimpleResponse></SimpleResponses>.  So you need to add another class in c# so you have two classes SimpleResponses and SimpleResponse.

Comment: @jdweng The client and the server both have a SimpleResponse Class.

Comment: The net library doesn't support xml serialization when the root tag is a list.  I think a simple solution is to create a c# class for SimpleResponses and then add one property which is a List<SimpleResponse>.

Comment: @jdweng - So what you're saying is create a SimpleResponses class that simply has a List<SimpleResponse> in it?

Comment: Exactly.  Then send the SimpleResponses as Post/Response.

Comment: @jdweng - Still not hitting the Server Post function.

Comment: Can you go back to when it was working without the list?  There should not be any difference between what was working and what you have now except before you had SimpleResponse as the root and now you have SimpleResponses as the root.

Comment: @jdweng - The post function on the4 API is getting the request but the request is null.

Comment: Looks like the JSON is getting deserialize.  Doesn't like the array.  You need to capture the JSON string and Post. I'm not that good a JSON array issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved the issues and can now successfully send multiple .docx files to the API and get the .pdf files back from the API. Now I want to figure out how to send each files on it's own thread instead of all together.

Client:

```
        public async void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseApiUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

                // Add an Accept header for JSON format.    
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, BaseApiUrl + ApiUrl);

                List<string> requests = new List<string>();
                byte[] bte;
                foreach (string s in docPaths)
                {
                     bte = File.ReadAllBytes(s);

                    requests.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(bte));
                }

                var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requests);

                request.Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage response1 = await client.PostAsync(BaseApiUrl + ApiUrl, request.Content);
                Task<string> json = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SimpleResponse>>(json.Result);

                foreach (SimpleResponse sr in response)
                {
                    if (sr.Success)
                    {
                        bte = Convert.FromBase64String(sr.Result.ToString());

                        string rs = RandomString(16, true);
                        string pdfFileName = tempPdfPath + rs + ".pdf";
                        
                        if (File.Exists(pdfFileName))
                        {
                            File.Delete(pdfFileName);
                        }
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFileName, bte);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

API:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<List<SimpleResponse>> Post([FromBody] List<string> request)
        {
            List<SimpleResponse> responses = new List<SimpleResponse>();

            try
            {
                Converter convert = new Converter();

                foreach (string s in request)
                {
                    var result = convert.CovertDocToPDF(s, WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempDocPath"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tempPdfPath"]);

                    responses.Add(new SimpleResponse()
                    {
                        Result = result,
                        Success = true
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responses.Add(new SimpleResponse()
                {
                    Result = null,
                    Success = true,
                    Exception = ex,
                    Errors = new List<string>() { string.Format("{0}, {1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException?.Message ?? "") }
                });
            }

            return responses;
        }
```