# How to send an HTTP PUT request using urllib2 or requests

Tags: django, python-2.7

In my Django app I need to send an HTTP PUT request to a url.
What is the proper syntax for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to do HTTP PUT in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-any-way-to-do-http-put-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
req = urllib2.Request(url=your_url, data=your_data)
req.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'