# Uploading file using socket and Put with Python

Tags: python, file, sockets, upload, put

I am trying to upload a file to the server in a simple way and I am getting the following error:

HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required

Content-Type: text/html

Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2015 03:05:33 GMT

Connection: close

Content-Length: 24

Length Required

I tried to insert length in different parts and looks like is not working, any suggestions?

```
import socket
import httplib
import os.path

target_host = "192.168.1.1"
target_port = 80
total_size = os.path.getsize('/root/test.html')

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect((target_host,target_port))

client.send("PUT /root/test.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:192.168.1.1\r\n\r\n" )

response = client.recv(4096)

print response
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing this with [requests?](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

You could easily specify the missing content-length header that is causing your error.

Comment: I tried both solutions and none of them help me to upload the file

Comment: Did you set the content-length header?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: [Is there any way to do HTTP PUT in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-any-way-to-do-http-put-in-python)

Here's an example using the requests library:

```
payload = {'username': 'me', 'email': 'me@me.com'}
>>> r = requests.put("http://somedomain.org/endpoint", data=payload)
```