# Need help adding API PUT method to Python script

Tags: python, api, put

I am using the script below to collect inventory information from servers and send it to a product called Device42. The script currently works however one of the APIs that I'm trying to add uses PUT instead of POST. I'm not a programmer and just started using python with this script. This script is using iron python. Can the PUT method be used in this script?

```
"""
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
"""
##################################################
# a sample script to show how to use
#   /api/ip/add-or-update
#   /api/device/add-or-update
#
# requires ironPython (http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) and
# powershell (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929)
##################################################

import clr

clr.AddReference('System.Management.Automation')

from System.Management.Automation import (
PSMethod, RunspaceInvoke
)
RUNSPACE = RunspaceInvoke()

import urllib
import urllib2
import traceback
import base64
import math
import ssl
import functools
BASE_URL='https://device42_URL'

API_DEVICE_URL=BASE_URL+'/api/1.0/devices/'
API_IP_URL    =BASE_URL+'/api/1.0/ips/'
API_PART_URL=BASE_URL+'/api/1.0/parts/'
API_MOUNTPOINT_URL=BASE_URL+'/api/1.0/device/mountpoints/'
API_CUSTOMFIELD_URL=BASE_URL+'/api/1.0/device/custom_field/'

USER     ='usernme'
PASSWORD ='password'

old_init = ssl.SSLSocket.__init__
@functools.wraps(old_init)
def init_with_tls1(self, *args, **kwargs):
kwargs['ssl_version'] = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
old_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
ssl.SSLSocket.__init__ = init_with_tls1

def post(url, params):
"""
http post with basic-auth
params is dict like object
"""
try:
    data= urllib.urlencode(params) # convert to ascii chars
    headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Basic '+ base64.b64encode(USER + ':' + PASSWORD),
        'Content-Type'  : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)

    print '---REQUEST---',req.get_full_url()
    print req.headers
    print req.data

    reponse = urllib2.urlopen(req)

    print '---RESPONSE---'
    print reponse.getcode()
    print reponse.info()
    print reponse.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
    print '---RESPONSE---'
    print err.getcode()
    print err.info()
    print err.read()
except urllib2.URLError as err:
    print '---RESPONSE---'
    print err

def to_ascii(s):
    # ignore non-ascii chars
    return s.encode('ascii','ignore')

def wmi(query):
    return [dict([(prop.Name, prop.Value) for prop in psobj.Properties]) for psobj in RUNSPACE.Invoke(query)]
def closest_memory_assumption(v):
    return int(256 * math.ceil(v / 256.0))

def add_or_update_device():
    computer_system  = wmi('Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -Namespace "root\CIMV2"')[0] # take first
    bios             = wmi('Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS -Namespace "root\CIMV2"')[0]
    operating_system = wmi('Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Namespace "root\CIMV2"')[0]
    environment      = wmi('Get-WmiObject Win32Reg_ESFFarmNode -Namespace "root\CIMV2"')[0]
    mem              = closest_memory_assumption(int(computer_system.get('TotalPhysicalMemory')) / 1047552)
    dev_name         = to_ascii(computer_system.get('Name')).upper()
    fqdn_name        = to_ascii(computer_system.get('Name')).upper() + '.' + to_ascii(computer_system.get('Domain')).lower()
device = {
    'memory'        : mem,
    'os'            : to_ascii(operating_system.get('Caption')),
    'osver'         : operating_system.get('OSArchitecture'),
    'osmanufacturer': to_ascii(operating_system.get('Manufacturer')),
    'osserial'      : operating_system.get('SerialNumber'),
    'osverno'       : operating_system.get('Version'),
    'service_level' : environment.get('Environment'),
    'notes'         : 'Test w/ Change to Device name collection'
}
devicedmn = ''
for dmn in ['Domain1', 'Domain2', 'Domain3', 'Domain4', 'Domain5']:
    if dmn == to_ascii(computer_system.get('Domain')).strip():
        devicedmn = 'Domain'
        device.update({ 'name' : fqdn_name, })
        break    
if devicedmn != 'Domain':
    device.update({
        'name': dev_name,
        })
manufacturer = ''
for mftr in ['VMware, Inc.', 'Bochs', 'KVM', 'QEMU', 'Microsoft Corporation', 'Xen']:
    if mftr == to_ascii(computer_system.get('Manufacturer')).strip():
        manufacturer = 'virtual'
        device.update({ 'manufacturer' : 'vmware', })
        break    
if manufacturer != 'virtual':
    device.update({
        'manufacturer': to_ascii(computer_system.get('Manufacturer')).strip(),
        'hardware': to_ascii(computer_system.get('Model')).strip(),
        'serial_no': to_ascii(bios.get('SerialNumber')).strip(),
        'type': 'Physical',
        })    
cpucount = 0
for cpu in wmi('Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor  -Namespace "root\CIMV2"'):
    cpucount += 1
    cpuspeed = cpu.get('MaxClockSpeed')
    cpucores = cpu.get('NumberOfCores')
if cpucount > 0:

    device.update({
        'cpucount': cpucount,
        'cpupower': cpuspeed,
        'cpucore':  cpucores,
        })
hddcount = 0
hddsize = 0
for hdd in wmi('Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk  -Namespace "root\CIMV2" | where{$_.Size -gt 1}'):
    hddcount += 1
    hddsize += hdd.get('Size') / 1073741742
if hddcount > 0:

    device.update({
        'hddcount': hddcount,
        'hddsize': hddsize,
        })
post(API_DEVICE_URL, device)

for hdd in wmi('Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk  -Namespace "root\CIMV2" | where{$_.Size -gt 1}'):
    mountpoint = {
          'mountpoint' : hdd.get('Name'),
          'label' : hdd.get('Caption'),
          'fstype' : hdd.get('FileSystem'),
          'capacity' : hdd.get('Size') / 1024 / 1024,
          'free_capacity' : hdd.get('FreeSpace') / 1024 / 1024,
          'device' : dev_name,
          'assignment' : 'Device',
    }
    post(API_MOUNTPOINT_URL, mountpoint)

network_adapter_configuration = wmi('Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Namespace "root\CIMV2" | where{$_.IPEnabled -eq "True"}')

for ntwk in network_adapter_configuration:
    for ipaddr in ntwk.get('IPAddress'):
        ip = {
            'ipaddress'  : ipaddr,
            'macaddress' : ntwk.get('MACAddress'),
            'label'      : ntwk.get('Description'),
            'device'     : dev_name,
        }
        post(API_IP_URL, ip)

def main():
    try:
        add_or_update_device()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yes, `PUT` method could be used, but you need to write it first.

Comment: I tried adding PUT by basically copying the "def post" section and modifying it to use put. I then added a section with the data i wanted to be "put" to the API but i keep getting a message that the API only allows PUT, meaning that the script is still trying to do a POST.

Answer (score 1):

Ok first things first you need to understand the difference between PUT and POST. I would write it out but another member of the community gave a very good description of the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request).

Now, yes you can use requests with that script. Here is an example of using the requests library by python, in order to install requests if you have pip installed install it like this:

```
pip install requests
```

Now, lest go through some examples of using the Requests library, the documentation can be found [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

HTTP Get Request. So for this example, you call the get function from the request library, give the url as parameter, then you can print out the text from the touple that is returned. Since GET will return something, it will generally be in the text portion of the touple allowing you to print it.

```
r = requests.get('http://urlhere.com/apistuffhere')
print(r.text)
```

HTTP POST: Posting to a url, depending on how the API was set up will return something, it generally does for error handling, but you also have to pass in parameters. Here is an example for a POST request to a new user entry. And again, you can print the text from the touple to check the response from the API

```
payload = {'username': 'myloginname', 'password': 'passwordhere'}
r = requests.post('https://testlogin.com/newuserEntry', params=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Alternatively you can print just r and it should return you a response 200 which should be successful.

For PUT: You have to keep in mind put responses can not be cacheable, so you can post data to the PUT url, but you will not know if there is an error or not but use the same syntax as POST. I have not tried to print out the text response in a PUT request using the Request library as I don't use PUT in any API I write.

```
requests.put('http://urlhere.com/putextension')
```

Now for implementing this into your code, you already have the base of the url, in your post for the login just do:

```
payload = {'username': USERNAME, 'passwd':PASSWORD}
r = requests.post('https://loginurlhere.com/', params=payload)
#check response by printing text
print (r.text)
```

As for putting data to an extension of your api, let us assume you already have a payload variable ready with the info you need, for example the API device extension:

```
requests.put(API_DEVICE, params=payload)
```

And that should PUT to the url. If you have any questions comment below and I can answer them if you would like.

Comment: I found this information, however further research made it seem as though the requests module doesn't work with iron python or at the very least it's challenging to make work.

Comment: You can do the same type of requests with urllib2, it is just more tedious than using the requests library.

Answer (score 0):

My standard answer would be to replace urllib2 with the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package. It makes doing HTTP work a lot easier.

But take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111988/63802) for a 'hack' to get PUT working.